# Show time when executing command in Konsole

Tags: linux, time, kde-plasma, konsole

Is there any way to show in the konsole the time when a command was executed? Something like: 
user@pc:~$ ls                                                            13:05

user@pc:~$ cd folder/                                                    13:06

user@pc:~$ cd ..                                                         13:07

Comment: http://bneijt.nl/blog/post/add-a-timestamp-to-your-bash-prompt/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your prompt to contain a timestamp.  This will depend on the shell you're using (probably bash), instead of the terminal emulator (konsole).  Assuming you are using bash, alter your $PS1 environment variable to contain the output of a command that prints the time, such as `date`:

`$ PS1="$PS1: $(date -R) >"`

Using that as a starting point, design a prompt you like.  `man date` to see the different ways you can print out the date/time.

After finding a command that gives you what you want, add it to your ~/.bashrc file to make it permanent.

Comment: This answer will work, but it looks like @Maxim gave a link in that comment that provides a more thorough explication of the solution.